# Error reading data from Firebase Realtimes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How can I correct these errors?
thank you

Comment: instead of adding a screenshot of code please insert your code specifying your error in question itself and please go through this 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try using null operator in the snapshot. The snapshot can be null

Comment: @suzan It does not work, I always have the same error of underlining